# How can I add library import to antlr4 in go?

Tags: go, import, antlr4

I started studying antlr and its work with go recently. And I have a problem with importing when using the library inside go. For example, I have at the beginning of my antlr file:

```
grammar Test;

@header {
    import "strconv"
}
```

And compile it with the following command `antlr4 -Dlanguage=Go Test.g4`. And then I have two files `parser` which uses this package and `lexer` which contains an import that is not used, which is why I cannot compile my project.

I expect that with the help of some flags I will be able to compile my project.

Comment: Why did you import an unused package?

Comment: All imports must be used in a valid Go program.

Comment: So I use this package inside my parser, but antlr also generate lexer with this import and lexer that doesn't use it

Comment: Antlr 4.11.1 already generates a parser containing an import of strconv (with a use shortly after to kill the error). You should not use `@header` or even `@parser:header` of `strconv` -- it's completely unnecessary, and in fact, kills "target agnostic" format. Make sure you are using the latest Antlr release, and you import `github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr/v4`, never`github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr` *anywhere*. We spent a lot of time cleaning up the Go target to make it work--still a ton more to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@parser::header` to include it only in the parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick and force the package to be used, for example, by writing `var _= strconv.Atoi`. Then the header will look like this:

```
@header {
    import "strconv"
    var _ = strconv.Atoi
}
```